# Cannot link freetype.a on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, freetype

i try to use freetype lib in my project with cocos2d-x. I built freetype and added to the project(like here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Installation/Android_NDK#FreeType ). In xcode it builds without errors. Now I trying to use it on android. I made make file in freetype dir:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := freetype
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/libfreetype.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/freetype2

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

and added to main makefile

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := freetype curl_static_prebuilt
...
$(call import-module,freetype)
```

during linking has the error: **libfreetype.a: file format not recognized; treating as linker script**

> Prebuilt       : libfreetype.a <=
>   /Users/user/Development/Slots/Slots_Android/lib/freetype/lib/
>   SharedLibrary  : libgame.so
>   /Users/user/Development/android_ndk_r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:./obj/local/armeabi/libfreetype.a:
>   file format not recognized; treating as linker script
>   /Users/user/Development/android_ndk_r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:./obj/local/armeabi/libfreetype.a:1:
>   syntax error collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

How to fix it?

Comment: Is the libfreetype.a library compiled using a compiler that generates binaries for the ARM architecture?

Comment: I think so. I used android-ndk-r8b and the following commands:
`./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=/freetype --without-zlib`

`make -j4`

`make install DESTDIR=$(pwd)`

Comment: Why do you run that command? You should build the library as a module and run **ndk-build**. Anyway, I think that you are building the libfreetype.a library with a different compiler version than the one you have in the NDK, and the linker from inside the NDK toolchain sees that and chokes. After you run configure GNU make will use the default compiler from path not the cross compiler for ARM.